# formulario validación, php

Tags: php, html

trato de que mande de un mensaje de error cuando los campos estén vacios, pero el problema es que recarga la pagina y el formulario se cierra. lo que intento hacer es que no recarga la pagina y muestre los mensajes de error sin actualizar la pagina

```
<div class="form-content" id="new">
                <form id="reg"  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                  <input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($USER)) echo $USER ?>" name="login-id" id="User" onkeypress="return pulsar(event)" placeholder="USERNAME" class="field" >
                  <input type="email" value="<?php if (isset($email)) echo $email ?>" name="email" id="usremail" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS" onkeypress="return pulsar(event)" class="field" >
                  <input type="password" id="ps" name="usrpw" placeholder="PASSWORD" class="field" onkeypress="return pulsar(event)" >
                    <span toggle="#password-field" onclick="toggleUse()" id="span2" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                  <button type="submit" id="Submit" name="register-button" class="flat-button signin">Sign Up</button>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="promo" id="promo-check" class="check" checked><label for="promo-check" class="check-label secondary-text promo">I'd like to receive special offers and discount coupons. No spam!</label>
                    <?php
                    include 'js/Verification.php';
                    ?>
                </form>
```

```
<?php

    $USER = $_POST['login-id'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $Pass = $_POST['usrpw'];

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['register-button'])) {
        if (empty($USER)) {
            echo "<p class='Errors'> * Campo Username no puede estar vacio</p>";
        }
        if (empty($email)) {
            echo "<p class='Errors'> * Campo Email no puede estar vacio</p>";
        }
        if (empty($Pass)) {
            echo "<p class='Errors'> * Campo Password no puede estar vacio</p>";
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Solo con php no lo vas a lograr, para ese propósito de nor recargar la página requieres JS

Comment: Por otro lado no me queda claro solo buscas validar que el formulario no esté vacío? o vas a hacer alguna otra operación con ellos en php?

Comment: tambien validare  mas cosas,  alguna sugerencia de como lo podría hacer con JS?

Comment: Si solo dame unos minutos e incluiré ajax

Comment: Una aclaración. Es importante recordar que debería ser OBLIGATORIO hacer la validación en la parte de backend, y OPCIONAL la validación de frontend. El efecto de no recargar la página es cosa de ui, y es importante, pero si alguien desactiva el JavaScript puede que a) tu página no funcione o b) que puedan saltarse tus validaciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas haciendo un post con y validando con PHP, usa JavaScript para validar con eso puedes validar un campo sin enviar el post , crea un archivo JS y lo insertas en tu html

```
 <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
```

tu form debera tener un metodo que se ejcute al ser enviado

```
  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="" id="" name="" onsubmit="return validacion()">
   ...
  </form>
```

Y en el Js pones tus condiciones

```
  function validacion() {


if (condicion que debe cumplir el primer campo del formulario) {
    // Si no se cumple la condicion...
    alert('[ERROR] El campo debe tener un valor de...');
    return false;
  }
  else if (condicion que debe cumplir el segundo campo del formulario) {
    // Si no se cumple la condicion...
    alert('[ERROR] El campo debe tener un valor de...');
    return false;
  }
  ...
  else if (condicion que debe cumplir el último campo del formulario) {
    // Si no se cumple la condicion...
    alert('[ERROR] El campo debe tener un valor de...');
    return false;
  }

  // Si el script ha llegado a este punto, todas las condiciones
  // se han cumplido, por lo que se devuelve el valor true
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Sin embargo este código no hace llegar los valores al backend, considerando que en el ejercicio del OP se muestra que los usará después

Comment: Solo tiene que añadir el "accion" en el form, cuando el js retorne "true" lo enviara al php

Comment: No estaría de mas que lo agregues

Answer (score 0):

me parece que debes utilizar ajax para actualizar tu contenido html sin recargar la página. Para ello te sugiero que utilices la librería jQuery de acuerdo a los siguientes pasos:

1. Importar la librería jquery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

2. Ingresar el siguiente código js:

```
<script>
function ejecutar() {
$.ajax({
  url: "accion.php",
  method: "post",
  data: "parm1=valor1&parm2=valor2",
  async: true
}).done(function(html_rpta) {
  $('#div_resultado').html( html_rpta );
});
}
</script>
```

3. Asignar al evento clic de tu botón la función de js:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:ejecutar()" value="Ejecutar"/>
```

El "#div_resultado" sería donde tu quieres mostrar el mensaje desde php. Este enlace puede ser útil para tu solución: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Espero sea de utilidad.

Saludos

Comment: Tienes razón, lo voy a corregir. Gracias por la observación

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar que la página recargue, tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

- Evita el uso del `input` de tipo `submit` y en su lugar sustitúyelo por un `button`
- Recupera cada uno de los `inputs` por medio de js a través de su `id`
- La validación realizala con js ahi mismo en el archivo o desde otro
- Como veo que planeas mandarlo al backend con php, entonces haremos uso de una petición AJAX por medio de la API fetch
- No uses el atributo `action` a nivel del form, eso lo dejaremos para fetch
- Usa `FormData()` para mandar los valores al backend en formato de **clave, valor** por medio de AJAX
- En el `input` requieres el `id` para que JS lo pueda recuperar y manipular y el `name` para cuando ese valor llegue a PHP

**Ejemplo**

**En el frontend**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form  id="frm" method="POST">
        <input id="usuario" name="usuario" type="text"  />
        <button id="envia">Enviar</button>
    </form>
<script>
let envia   = document.getElementById("envia")
let usuario = document.getElementById("usuario")

envia.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
let datos = new FormData()
    datos.append("usuario", usuario.value)
    event.preventDefault()
    if (usuario.value === "") {
        console.log("Falta este valor")
    } else {
        fetch("app.php", {
            method: 'POST',
            body: datos
        }).then(response => response.text())
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
          })
    }
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**En el backend**

```
<?php 


$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];

echo "Hola: ".$usuario;
```